# OpenGL Cone Function Not Drawing Correctly

Tags: opengl, 3d, geometry

I found an example online that shows how to draw a cone in OpenGL, which is located [here](http://www.freemancw.com/2012/06/opengl-cone-function/): It was written in C++, and so I translated it to C#. Here is the new code:

```
        public void RenderCone(Vector3 d, Vector3 a, float h, float rd, int n)
        {
            Vector3 c = new Vector3(a + (-d * h));
            Vector3 e0 = Perp(d);
            Vector3 e1 = Vector3.Cross(e0, d);
            float angInc = (float)(360.0 / n * GrimoireMath.Pi / 180);

            // calculate points around directrix
            List<Vector3> pts = new List<Vector3>();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                float rad = angInc * i;
                Vector3 p = c + (((e0 * (float)Math.Cos((rad)) + (e1 * (float)Math.Sin(rad))) * rd));
                pts.Add(p);
            }

            // draw cone top
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan);
            GL.Vertex3(a);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(pts[i]);
            }
            GL.End();

            // draw cone bottom
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan);
            GL.Vertex3(c);
            for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(pts[i]);
            }
            GL.End();
        }

        public Vector3 Perp(Vector3 v)
        {
            float min = Math.Abs(v.X);
            Vector3 cardinalAxis = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
            if (Math.Abs(v.Y) < min)
            {
                min = Math.Abs(v.Y);
                cardinalAxis = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
            }
            if (Math.Abs(v.Z) < min)
            {
                cardinalAxis = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
            }
            return Vector3.Cross(v, cardinalAxis);
        }
```

I *think* I am using the parameters correctly(the page isnt exactly coherent in terms of actual function-usage). Here is the legend that the original creator supplied:

[image]

But when I enter in the following as parameters:

```
RenderCone(new Vector3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f), new Vector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f), 20.0f, 10.0f, 8);
```

I receive this(Wireframe enabled):

[image]

As you can see, I'm missing a slice, either at the very beginning, or the very end. Does anyone know what's wrong with this method? Or what I could be doing wrong that would cause an incomplete cone?

Answer (score 2):

```
        // draw cone bottom
        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan);
        GL.Vertex3(c);
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            GL.Vertex3(pts[i]);
        }
        GL.End();
```

That connects all vertices to each other and center but there is one connection missing. There is nothing the specifies connection from first to last vertex. Adding *GL.Vertex3(pts[n-1]);* after loop would add the missing connection.

Comment: I literally just noticed that, too. =P

Comment: If you want to draw triangles instead lines then you will need same connection for top too.

Comment: I was just rendering it in wireframe, I am still missing a side, trying to figure it out right now.

Comment: By "Same Connection" do you mean another GL.Vertex3(pts[n - 1]); after the "draw cone top" loop? Because it's not working for me. >_>

Answer (score 0):

The Solution was actually extremely simple, I needed to increase the number of slices by 1. Pretty special if you ask me.

```
        public void RenderCone(Vector3 baseToApexLength, Vector3 apexLocation, float height, float radius, int slices)
        {
            Vector3 c = new Vector3(apexLocation + (-baseToApexLength * height));
            Vector3 e0 = Perpendicular(baseToApexLength);
            Vector3 e1 = Vector3.Cross(e0, baseToApexLength);
            float angInc = (float)(360.0 / slices * GrimoireMath.Pi / 180);
            slices++; // this was the fix for my problem.
            /**
             * Compute the Vertices around the Directrix
             */
            Vector3[] vertices = new Vector3[slices];
            for (int i = 0; i < vertices.Length; ++i)
            {
                float rad = angInc * i;
                Vector3 p = c + (((e0 * (float)Math.Cos((rad)) + (e1 * (float)Math.Sin(rad))) * radius));
                vertices[i] = p;
            }

            /**
             * Draw the Top of the Cone.
             */
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan);
            GL.Vertex3(apexLocation);
            for (int i = 0; i < slices; ++i)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(vertices[i]);
            }
            GL.End();

            /**
             * Draw the Base of the Cone.
             */
            GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.TriangleFan);
            GL.Vertex3(c);
            for (int i = slices - 1; i >= 0; --i)
            {
                GL.Vertex3(vertices[i]);
            }
            GL.End();
        }
```